# How can I generate a large number of data points of a function and plot them?

Tags: plotting, data

Given a function `f[x_,y_,z_,a_]:=x^2 + xy+ yz + z^3+a^2` (just for example), how can I randomly choose values of `x,y,z,a` (with constraints that all $x,y,z$, and $a$ are positive, and `Sqrt[x^2+y^2+z^2]<=1`) and plot `f[x,y,z,a]` against `Sqrt[x^2+y^2+z^2]` for say 100 points $(x,y,z,a)$?

I am sure this is doable in Mathematica, but I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: Side note: "Randomly choosing a value" is not well-defined for infinite domains (in particular, choosing a random `a` is not really possible, since `a` could be anywhere from 0 to infinity). If you care about the randomness of the chosen points, you'll have to decide on a distribution for `a` that is well-defined.

Comment: It is recommend to answer a new question for the new edition and add this links to the new question.

Comment: Alright @cvgmt, thanks  for the info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

````
(* number of random points *)
nPoints = 100;

(* parametrize {x,y,z} in spherical coordinates *)
(* with the constraints theta<=pi/2 and phi<=pi/4 *)
(* to meet the constraints that x,y,z>0 *)
r = RandomReal[{0, 1}, nPoints];
theta = RandomReal[{0, Pi/2}, nPoints];
phi = RandomReal[{0, Pi/4}, nPoints];
{x, y, z} = {r Sin[theta] Cos[phi], r Sin[theta] Sin[phi], 
   r Cos[theta]};

(* I'm assuming a is <=aMax *)
aMax = 1;
a = RandomReal[{0, aMax}, nPoints];

Clear[f]
f[x_, y_, z_, a_] := x^2 + x y + y z + z^3 + a^2

data = Transpose[{r, f @@@ Transpose[{x, y, z, a}]}];
ListPlot[data]
```
````

Comment: Thanks @H. Zhou. I have a similar situation where now in place of $a$, there is a set $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5$ and they are real and also constrained to $\sum_{i=1}^{5} a_i = 1$. How to handle this situation?

Comment: @seeker If you mean a linear relation between a_i's then I think you can first generate random numbers for a_{1,2,3,4}, then compute a5=1-a1-a2-a3-a4.

Comment: Thanks, @H. Zhou, that works! However, I have a final constraint $|x \pm y| \le |1 \pm z|$ arising due to some physical reasons. How can I take this into account? Should I ask it as a new question?

Comment: @seeker For this one I would use ```Select```, in a similar way as that suggested by @Rom38.

Comment: Thanks @H. Zhou, but Rom38's approach (with due respect to his expertise) seems hard to me. Could you incorporate this in your answer?

Comment: The inequality $|x\pm y| \le |1\pm z|$ actually leads to four inequalities $z \ge x+y-1;  ~z\le -x+y+1;~z\le x-y+1;~z \ge -x-y-1.$

Comment: I invite you to my new question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/271948/generating-a-large-number-of-data-points-of-a-function-subjected-to-multiple-con

Answer (score 6):

How about

```
f[x_, y_, z_, a_] := x^2 + x y + y z + z^3 + a^2;
pts = RandomPoint[Ball[], n = 50000] //Abs// Transpose;
a = RandomReal[{0, 1}, n];
Map[{Norm[Most[#]], f @@ #} &, Transpose@Append[pts, a]] // ListPlot
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First, let's define the array of random sets:

```
args = RandomReal[{0, 2}, {50000, 4}];
```

I've limited the coordinates up to 2 but it can be any.
Let's take from `args` all the sets that fit the desired constrains are:

```
cnsts = Select[args, Norm[#[[1 ;; 3]]] <= 1 &];
```

The function is:

```
f = #[[1]]^2 + #[[1]] #[[2]] + #[[2]] #[[3]] + #[[3]]^3 + #[[4]]^2 &;
```

An array of values `{Norm@cnsts[[i,1;;3]],f@cnsts[[i]]}` is:

```
res = Table[{Norm[cnsts[[i, 1 ;; 3]]], f@cnsts[[i]]}, 
            {i, 1, Length@cnsts}];
```

And the plot is:

```
ListPlot[res, PlotLabel -> "Number of point = " <> ToString@Length@cnsts]
```

[image]

There 3315 random elements of `args`  fit with your constrains.

P.S. I don't understand why the bottom Axis appeared without Ticks but this is in range {0,1} according the constrains