# Generating a large number of data points of a function subjected to multiple constraints

Tags: plotting, data

In continuation to my [previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/271786/how-can-i-generate-a-large-number-of-data-points-of-a-function-and-plot-them), I have (a slightly modified) function
`f[x_,y_,z_,a_,b_,c_]:=x^2 a b  + xy b c+ yz c a + z^3 abc` , and I want to randomly choose values of `x,y,z,a,b,c` (with constraints that all $x,y,z$, and $a,b,c$ are positive, and `Sqrt[x^2+y^2+z^2]<=1` and `a+b+c=1`) and plot `f[x,y,z,a,b,c]` against `Sqrt[x^2+y^2+z^2]` for say 100 points $(x,y,z,a,b,c)$.

I am editing this question with additional constraints given by four inequalities $|x\pm y| \le |1\pm z|$ which simplify to  $z \ge x+y-1;  ~z\le -x+y+1;~z\le x-y+1;~z \ge -x-y-1.$

How can one take into account these?

EDIT: It was "all ... and $a,b,c$ are positive" and not just $a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_, y_, z_, a_, b_, c_] := 
  x^2*a*b + x*y*b*c + y*z*c*a + z^3*a*b*c

FullSimplify[Abs[x + y] <= Abs[1 + z] &&
  Abs[x + y] <= Abs[1 - z] &&
  Abs[x - y] <= Abs[1 + z] &&
  Abs[x - y] <= Abs[1 - z] &&
  x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0 &&
  Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2] <= 1]

(* x + y + z <= 1 && x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0 *)

param = FindInstance[{x > 0, y > 0, z > 0, a > 0, 
    Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2] <= 1, a + b + c == 1, x + y + z <= 1}, 
  {x, y, z, a, b, c}, Reals, 100];

pts = Simplify[{Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], f[x, y, z, a, b, c]} /. #] & /@
    param;

ListPlot[pts, Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], 
   HoldForm@f[x, y, z, a, b, c]}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Expanding the `PlotRange`

```
ListPlot[pts, Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2],
   HoldForm@f[x, y, z, a, b, c]},
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Or

```
ListPlot[pts, Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2],
   HoldForm@f[x, y, z, a, b, c]},
 PlotRange -> All,
 ScalingFunctions -> "SignedLog"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Bob Hanlon. Is it possible to avoid the symbols /. and /@ and /@# ? I mean I'm a beginner and find inconvenient working with this notation.

Comment: Highlight the unfamiliar symbol in Mathematica and press `F1` for help. The documentation will show you how to use the verbose form.

Comment: Yeah, I'm doing that and it helps! A doubt: & after # is supposed to "pump in" the expression into #. In the definition of pts, why is & followed  by Map /@ ? I was expecting  we simple pump the param into {Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], f[x, y, z, a, b, c]}.

Comment: The elements of `param` each look like `{x -> 209/3334, y -> 19/54, z -> 26351/45009, a -> 23, b -> -4, c -> -18}`, i.e., a list of rules. To create `pts` you want `{Sqrt[x^2+y^2+z^2], f[x, y, z, a, b, c]}` evaluated using each separate element of `param` in a `ReplaceAll` (`/.`). Consequently, the `ReplaceAll` is mapped (`/@`) onto `param`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
u=RandomReal[{0,1},{400,5}]; (*generate enough points to have >=100 acceptable points*)
v=Map[({x,y,z,a,b}=#;{x,y,z,a,b,1-a-b})&,u];(*c isn't really "random", calculate it*)
w=Take[Select[v,({x,y,z,a,b,c}=#;x^2+y^2+z^2<=1&&x+y-1<=z<=-x+y+1&&z>=-x-y-1)&],100];
f[x_,y_,z_,a_,b_,c_]:=x^2*a*b+x*y*b*c+y*z*c*a+z^3*a*b*c;
ListPlot[Map[({x,y,z,a,b,c}=#;{f[x,y,z,a,b,c], Sqrt[x^2+y^2+z^2]})&,w]]
```

Ah! Notice that I (or possibly the OP) made a mistake. He wrote "with constraints that all x,y,z, and a are positive" and I implemented "with constraints that all x,y,z,a,b are positive." If b really can be -9999999 then my code will need to be modified, perhaps in a similar way to how I generated c after the fact, to provide a different random range for b. And he didn't provide any bounds on the range of a, so it might possibly be 9999999. Both of those are going to make a VERY different plot. That just shows that you have to test my code VERY carefully to make certain that  you have discovered all of my errors.

Comment: Thanks @Bill, can you explain what's happening inside Map in the definition of v?

Comment: I would suggest using `Apply[Function[{x,y,z,a,b},...]]` instead of `Function[{x,y,z,a,b}=#;...]`. It is a lot easier to read (at least to me), and doesn't affect global variables.

Comment: @seeker You wrote "I want to randomly choose values of x,y,z,a,b,c" Great. generate 6 random numbers each time. But then you add "a+b+c=1" and that will almost never be true for 6 random numbers. So generate 5 random numbers each time and use those to calculate the value of c thus turning a list of 5 numbers into a list of 6 numbers where c=1-a-b. Does that help any? Anything in MMA can be written in at least 12 different ways. One other way is `v=Map[Append[#,1-#[[-2]]-#[[-1]]]&,u]` But as I added above, there is no range given for either `a` or `b` maybe not limited between 0 and 1. Helps?

Comment: Thanks @Bill, I understand your approach, it is just that I find it a bit hard to follow the Syntax like Map[({x,y,z,a,b}=#;{x,y,z,a,b,1-a-b})&,u]. I am totally lost by  ( {  }=#; {  } ) &.  I understand Map[f, expr] make f to act on each element on the first level in expr.

Comment: @seeker It is very good that you `Map`. MMA programming has a culture of turning lots of things into cryptic punctuation characters and that takes time to learn to accept. What someone finds hard to follow is partly the result of how they defined the MMA language. Now `({x,y,z,a,b}=#;{x,y,z,a,b,1-a-b})&` is the function. You can tell that by the `(...)&` You can look up `Function` in help, but that may not "help" you much. Or I could rewrite the code `f[v_]:=({x,y,z,a,b}=v;{x,y,z,a,b,1-a-b});Map[f,u]` Does that help? But that isn't the usual MMA way of writing this. Can you follow better now?

Comment: Thanks @Bill. That helped!