# What does the operation Map[({...}=#;{...})&, ] do?

Tags: symbols, operators

With reference to the answer by @Bill to the question posted [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/271948/generating-a-large-number-of-data-points-of-a-function-subjected-to-multiple-con/271966?noredirect=1#comment679101_271966), I am trying to understand the following three lines

```
  u = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {20, 5}]
  v = Map[({x, y, z, a, b} = #; {x, y, z, a, b, 1 - a - b}) &, u]
  w = Take[Select[v, ({x, y, z, a, b, c} = #;  x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1 && x + y - 1 <= z <= -x + y + 1 && z >= -x - y - 1) &], 3]
```

Clearly `u` generates $20 \times 5$ array of random (real) numbers between 0 and 1. But I do not understand how `Map[({x, y, z, a, b} = #; {x, y, z, a, b, 1 - a - b}) &, u]` is working. Both `v` and `w` involve something like  `({}=#;{})&`. What does this operation do?

Comment: `Map[function,listOfData]` is going to "do" that `function` to each element in that list of `data` and give back a list of results. In this case the function assigns values to `x,y,z,a,b` from the five items in each element of the data. Then it creates a new 6 item list made up of the first 5 items and the calculated value for `c`. And then the third line will select all the items that satisfy the conditions and then Take will take just the first 3 of those. (That was my code answering your question, by the way) If you need a longer more detailed answer I can try to do that.

Comment: You might find the function traceview2 in this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29340/86543) interesting when trying to understand the evaluation sequence of a code. I tried it with the problem you gave by surrounding the whole code like TraceView2[line1;line2;line3]. It might take some time learning how to navigate through the cells.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Effectively, `{a,b}=...` sets both `a` and `b` simultaneously to the corresponding elements of the right side (see [`Set`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html)). So for example:

```
{a, b} = {1, 2};

a
(* 1 *)

b
(* 2 *)
```

Now, in your example, we can look at what the function (the `(...)&`, see also [`Function`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html)) gets as argument using [`Echo`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Echo.html):

```
u = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3, 5}];
v = Map[({x, y, z, a, b} = Echo@#; {x, y, z, a, b, 1 - a - b}) &, u]

(* {0.524485,0.374012,0.209276,0.447658,0.534618} *)
(* {0.945336,0.0270697,0.206729,0.00877572,0.881564} *)
(* {0.725822,0.263445,0.160514,0.247397,0.798175} *)
(* {{0.524485, 0.374012, 0.209276, 0.447658, 0.534618, 
  0.0177245}, {0.945336, 0.0270697, 0.206729, 0.00877572, 0.881564, 
  0.10966}, {0.725822, 0.263445, 0.160514, 0.247397, 
  0.798175, -0.0455723}} *)
```

So it just gets one row from the 20x5 matrix, as expected. This now means that `{x,y,z,a,b}` get set to those 5 values. The second part is then the result of the function, so using the just set values for `a,b,x,y,z`, we compute the list `{x,y,z,a,b,1-a-b}`. This is then returned from the function (see also [`CompoundExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CompoundExpression.html)).

That being said, I would have rewritten the line as follows:

```
v = Apply[Function[{x, y, z, a, b}, {x, y, z, a, b, 1 - a - b}], u, {1}];
```

This applies (see [`Apply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html)) the function taking 5 arguments (called `x,y,z,a,b`) to each row of the matrix, and then computes the same expression as before. I just find it a lot more explicit in what's going on, and it doesn't needlessly modify global variables.

The third line follows the same logic, so we can use a similar strategy to rewrite it for improved readability:

```
w = Take[Select[v, Apply@Function[{x, y, z, a, b, c}, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1 && x + y - 1 <= z <= -x + y + 1 && z >= -x - y - 1]], 3]
```

Notice here that I used the operator form of [`Apply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html). This effectively converts the function `Function[{x,y,z,a,b,c},...]` which takes 6 arguments into a function that takes a list of length 6 as a single argument. This is required since [`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) will pass the lists of length 6 as a single argument to the filter criterion. The `Apply` then effectively splits this list into separate arguments.

Comment: Thanks @Lukas Lang, how can I write ListPlot[Map[({x,y,z,a,b,c}=#;{f[x,y,z,a,b,c], Sqrt[x^2+y^2+z^2]})&,w]]  in simpler form as you wrote those v  and w?

Comment: @seeker `ListPlot[Map[Apply@Function[{x,y,z,a,b,c}, {f[...],...}], w]]` or equivalently `ListPlot[Apply[Function[{x,y,z,a,b,c},{f[...],...}],w,{1}]]`